# A polynomial that sends every eigenvalue to its conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a normal operator on a complex space with eigenvalues $c_1,...,c_n$, then there is a polynomial $p$ such that $p(c_i)=\bar c_i$.

I am trying to use the fact that $<v_i,c_iv_i>=\bar c_i$ (assuming $v_i$ is a normal eigenvector for $c_i$). It would be good if I could define $p(c_i)=<v,c_iv>$ for a specifc $v$ but it is not reasonable and I havent used the condition that T is normal.

Hints are appreciated.

Comment: In principle this is just a routine linear algebra problem, you're given $n$ pairs of complex numbers $(x_i,y_i)$ and you want to find their polynomial interpolant. The only reason to do it any other way from that is if there's some nicer way to construct $p$ using $T$.

Comment: There no need for a nicer $p$. Thanks!